# Linq - Retrieve first list after SelectMany

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I've an object list where each object contains an internal object list and what I would fetching is the father list (left list), however I'm forced to use SelectMany function..Is it possibile?

Naive Example:

```
var query = objList.SelectMany(p => p.InternalList)
                   .Where(internalObj => internalObj.SomeProprerty == true)
                   .SELECT(objList);
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't *actually* want `objList`, but instead the element of `objList` which we're looking at at the time, I think you just want:

```
var query = objList.SelectMany(p => p.InternalList, (o, p) => new { o, p })
                   .Where(pair => pair.p.SomeProperty)
                   .Select(pair => pair.o);
```

If that's not what you're after, it would really help if you'd give a concrete example.

EDIT: If you only want *any* example from `objList` where any element of the internal list has a `SomeProperty` value of `true`, you can do that more easily like this:

```
var value = objList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.InternalList.Any(p => p.SomeProperty));
if (value != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to retrieve an object where just one element of its internalList contains a proprerty where its value is true.

Comment: @bit: The code I've given you will give you all of those, possibly with repeats. But there's a better way of doing it - will edit.

Comment: Waiting for your new edit, I've tried your first solution but I've achieved error on compilation time { o, p } => is bad..

Comment: Or just change the `FirstOrDefault` to `Where` and you'll get a list of all `objList` items where at least one object in its `InternalList` has the property value you want.